# Rewrite URL (Apache): Creating 301 redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I recently restructured my site, moving away from querystring parameters to friendly urls.  The url structure I used to use was `mysite.com/?site=www.somesite.com/`.  I am now using the `site` parameter as part of the page's path, with my new url structure being `mysite.com/site/www.somesite.com`

I cannot figure out the proper rewrite rule to for my `.htaccess` file to redirect the old url structure to the new

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* /site/%1 [L,R=301]
```

**Edit:** In reply to comment #3

Change `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule .* /site/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: But this not solving situation, it is 'closer' to solution, but after adding this, my URLs are redirected to:

Comment: THIS-> http://www.mysite.com/site/www.somesite.com/?site=www.somesite.com/    ,and I need -> http://www.mysite.com/site/somesite.com ,so how to 'tweak' this redirect I think this is in good direction but don't know what else to do to get those results?